# Assign lables to factors in R using .csv-file

Tags: r, csv, factors, levels

I am working with a .csv file in R that has one column that I want to treat as a factor. It contains numbers.

```
variable1
1 
2
4
4
1
3
and so on
```

I now want to assign lables to this factor variable. What I did worked:

```
v1$variable1 <- factor(v1$variable1,
                            levels = c(1,2,3, 4, 5, 6 (and so on)),
                            labels = c("school 1", "school 2", "school 3", "school 4", "school 5",
                                       "school 6" (and so on))
```

However, the list of schools is quite dynamic and instead of altering the code each time it would be much more elegant to have another csv file containing the levels and lables like this:

```
level   lables
1       school1
2       school2
3       school3
and so on
```

and then to read in that csv file into the R code and assign the lables based on this second cvs file. Is this possible and if so, how?

Thanks a lot for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create another csv in `v2`, you can use `match` to match  `variable1` with `level` and get the corresponding `lables`.

```
v1$variable2 <- v2$lables[match(v1$variable1, v2$level)]
v1$variable2 <- factor(v1$variable2)
```

---

Perhaps, a `merge` would also work in this case

```
v1 <- merge(v1, v2, by.x = 'variable1', by.y = 'level')
```

Comment: The merge-thing worked! Thank you very, very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you use a look table as you suggest you could do ...

```
school_lut <- data.frame(
  value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  label = c("Cambridge", "Bezt school", "R", "S", "Holly")
)

school_lut_ss <- school_lut[school_lut$value %in% df$var1, ]
# Previous step only needed to eliminate levels you don't have in your data
df$var1 <- factor(df$var1, school_lut_ss$value, school_lut_ss$label)

table(df$var1)

# Cambridge Bezt school           S       Holly 
#         1           4           1           2
```

Data

```
set.seed(12)
df <- data.frame(
  var1 = sample(1:5, size = 8, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! No, "school1" etc. was just a placeholder, these are actually real school names.

Comment: @Fabienne Updated. Also you could use `droplevels()` to eliminate empty levels after converting to factor.

Comment: Thank you again! I will look into it and see whether I understand it ;),